# s.replace HTML within a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, replace

I have HTML within a string where I am trying to replace the following:

```
<td colspan="12" bgcolor="#460F59">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<font color="#ffffff"><b>IT  </b> 
            <b>214 </b>&#150; <font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Fund of Software Develop </b> 
            <b>&nbsp;(4 Credits)</b></font></font></td>
```

with:

```
<td colspan="12" bgcolor="#460F59">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<font color="#ffffff"><b>IT  </b> 
            <b>214 </b>&#150; <font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Fund of Software Develop </b> 
            <b>&nbsp;(4 Credits) - Prereq: IT 210</b></font></font></td>
```

I realize the quotations need to be fixed but how can I show that the HTML is on 3 separate lines?

Actual Code:

```
 s.Replace("<td colspan="12" bgcolor="#460F59">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<font color="#ffffff"><b>IT  </b> 
        <b>214 </b>&#150; <font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Fund of Software Develop </b> 
        <b>&nbsp;(4 Credits)</b></font></font></td>", "<td colspan="12" bgcolor="#460F59">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<font color="#ffffff"><b>IT  </b> 
        <b>214 </b>&#150; <font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Fund of Software Develop </b> 
        <b>&nbsp;(4 Credits) - Prereq: IT 210</b></font></font></td>");
```

Comment: Could you post the actual code you are using to do the replace?

Comment: Can you please clarify "It is not working"? What do you have defined as "first section" and "second section"?

Comment: The code you have posted will not compile.  Are you trying to figure out how to escape `"` in a string?

Comment: What you want?Don't use any "" in inside of "" .Only using "''" this format .and s.replace("<td......","")

Comment: I forgot the @ in addition to """"  Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Make sure when you do a replace in C# you're assigning the output:

```
var s = "test";
s = s.Replace("t","b");
```

Otherwise `s` won't change.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try to replace

```
<b>&nbsp;(4 Credits)</b></font></font></td>
```

with

```
<b>&nbsp;(4 Credits) - Prereq: IT 210</b></font></font></td>
```

As far as I can see, the other lines don't change at all?

Comment: It looks like he's trying to list a prerequisite course for the course bing listed. I imagine he probably needs to replace based on the value of "<b>IT  </b><b>214 </b>"